# How to configure Git when using it in different settings

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Till now I've used Git with GitHub personally, but I'm starting to use it professionally with GitLab using a different (company) e-mail address.

In https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html it is explained how to run the `git config --global` commands when setting it up. I assume this would overwrite my 'personal' settings. Is there away to create two 'instances' of Git, one for personal and one for professional use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the repository, and use `git config` without `--global` switch.

The [default switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) is `--local`

That will set new email for this particular repository and will keep your global settings.

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/#setting-your-email-address-for-a-single-repository